# Tag synonym [mailserver] -> [emailserver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

For me there is not a difference for the tags mailserver and emailserver so I would suggest to create a Tag synonym [mailserver] -> [emailserver]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good call. Done.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​